# Node.js: splitting a readable stream pipe to multiple sequential writable streams

Tags: node.js, stream

Given a `Readable` stream (which may be `process.stdin` or a file stream), is it possible/practical to `pipe()` to a custom `Writable` stream that will fill a child `Writable` until a certain size; then close that child stream; open a new `Writable` stream and continue?

(The context is to upload a large piece of data from a pipeline to a CDN, dividing it up into blocks of a reasonable size as it goes, without having to write the data to disk first.)

I've tried creating a `Writable` that handles the opening and closing of the child stream in the `_write` function, but the problem comes when the incoming chunk is too big to fit in the existing child stream: it has to write some of the chunk to the old stream; create the new stream; and then wait for the `open` event on the new stream before completing the `_write` call.

The other thought I had was to create an extra `Duplex` or `Transform` stream to buffer the pipe and ensure that the chunk coming into the `Writable` is definitely equal to or less than the amount the existing child stream can accept, to give the `Writable` time to change the child stream over.

Alternatively, is this overcomplicating everything and there's a much easier way to do the original task?

Answer (score 3):

I bumped across the question when looking for an answer for a related problem. How to parse a file and split it its lines into separate files depending on some category value in the line.

I did my best to change my code to make it more relevant to your problem. However, that's rapidly adapted. Not tested. Treat it as pseudo-code.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  through = require('through');

 var destCount = 0, dest, size = 0, MAX_SIZE = 1000;

readableStream
  .on('data', function(data) {
    var out = data.toString() + "\n";
    size += out.length;
    if(size > MAX_SIZE) {
      dest.emit("end");
      dest = null;
      size = 0;
    }
    if(!dest) {
      // option 1. manipulate data before saving them.
      dest = through();
      dest.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("log" + destCount))
      // option 2. write directly to file
      // dest = fs.createWriteStream("log" + destCount);
    }
    dest.emit("data", out);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    dest.emit('end');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would introduce a `Transform` in between the `Readable` and `Writable` stream. And in its `_transform`, I would do all the logic I would need.

Maybe, I would only have a Readable and a Transform only. The `_transform` method would create  all the Writable stream I need

Personally, I only use a Writable stream only when I'm dumping data somewhere and I would be done processing that chunk.
I avoid implementing `_read` and `_write` as much as I can and abuse Transform stream.

But the point I don't understand in your question is write about size. What do you mean by it.?

Comment: The goal is to continuously read data from a `Readable` stream up to 1GB passing through to a `Writable` stream.  Once 1GB is reached, the destination `Writable` stream needs to be closed and another opened, and then the process continues, reading from the same `Readable` stream from where it left off.

As the data is up to 5GB (the CDN's limit) and the cloud server involved has limited disk and memory space, I don't want to buffer it and then open a Writable: it needs to be a steady flow.